# patching a ravendb collection documents, adding $type on array items

Tags: c#, ravendb, patch

I have a collection on my Ravendb 3.5 named `Bills`, that has an array of `Items` (`Sale.Items`). I must patch the items, adding a `$type`, since I have moved the collection from a collection of `Item` to a collection of `ISaleItem`, so I need to tell Ravendb which concrete class it should serialize the item into.

i must patch the existing documents, adding a default. I must patch them from

```
{
    "Id":"1",
    "Sale":{
        "Date":"2018-05-01",
        "Operator":"Pete",
        "Items":[
            {
                "SKU":"ab01",
                "price":1000
            },
            {
                "SKU":"ab02",
                "price":1000
            },
            {
                "SKU":"ab03",
                "price":1000
            }

        ]
    }

}
```

to

```
{
    "Id":"1",
    "Sale":{
        "Date":"2018-05-01",
        "Operator":"Pete",
        "Items":[
            {
                "$type":"MyApp.Item,Myapp.Models",
                "SKU":"ab01",
                "price":1000
            },
            {
                "$type":"MyApp.Item,Myapp.Models",
                "SKU":"ab02",
                "price":1000
            },
            {
                "$type":"MyApp.Item,Myapp.Models",
                "SKU":"ab03",
                "price":1000
            }

        ]
    }

}
```

how do I write a patch script (js or c#) to do that?
thanks

**edit**: I've found this solution, to be executed in the patch page of ravendbstudio:

```
this.Sale.Items.forEach(function(el)
{
    el.$type="MyApp.Item,Myapp.Models";

});
```

please improve my solution if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Patch the collection through the ravendb studio using this:

```
if(this.Sale != null && this.Sale.Items != null && this.Sale.Items.length > 0)
{
    this.Sale.Items.Map(function(item){
        item["$type"] = "MyApp.Item,Myapp.Models";

        return item;
    });
}
```